# Paginación con PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas, necesito crear un sistema de paginación, para que sólo muestre 5 o 10 resultados (esto lo decidiré más adelante)

Se como traer los resultados pero no como limitarlo a 10 por ejemplo. Tengo esto de momento.

```html
<?php

 require_once 'conexion.php';
  
 $result;

 $conn = dbConnect();

 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos ORDER BY id DESC';

 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 $rows = $result->fetchAll();

 ?>
```

```html
<?php
     foreach ($rows as $row) {
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para paginar puedes utilizar LIMIT y OFFSET:

```
SELECT * FROM avisos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $items_per_page OFFSET $offset;
```

LIMIT limita el número de filas a devolver y OFFSET define el desplazamiento. En este caso el desplazamiento sería:

```
$offset = $page_number * $items_per_page;
```

LIMIT y OFFSET se pueden utilizar en notación abreviada de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT * FROM avisos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $items_per_page;
```

Si necesitas más información: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20364624/9209251

Comment: Podrías decirme como lo implemento? Soy nuevo en PHP y estoy un poco perdido la verdad

Comment: Defines un número de items por defecto: `$items_per_page = 10`. Si la petición es `http://example.com/aviso?page=0`, puedes capturar el parámetro de la siguiente forma: `$page_number = $_GET["page"]`. Con los dos parámetros ya puedes crear la petición y realizar la consulta tal y como tienes en tu código.